# Finding a reference to an Object among a list of Objects based on the name of a property

Tags: c#, search, object, reference, find

I have a `List<CustomClass> listOfCustomClass`.

CustomClass is defined as follows :

```
public class CustomClass {
   public name;
}
```

I want to search my List for a CustomClass of name "foo" and return a reference to this class. How can I do this ? The following is what I have attempted, however it returns "null".

```
CustomcClass class = listOfCustomClass.Find(delegate(CustomClass  findClass) {return findClass.name=="foo"; });
```

Comment: Well you didn't try exactly that code, because `class` is a keyword. How about you produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a linq query...

```
var customClass = listOfCustomClass.Where(c => c.name == "foo").SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

use linq:

```
var returnedItem=(from item in listOfCustomClass
                  where item.name=="blah"
                  select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

It also has the advantage of being very readable

To get you started, here are 101 linq examples: [linq examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Life is better with Linq